# Rails method to assign instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails class `Datatable` that returns an `as_json` object.

I want to then take that object and assign it to several instance vars to update partials, so when a user calls a myriad of ajax options, I can do one json object server-side, assign them to vars server-side, and reload by partial erb.

How can I call `Model.refresh_objects` to use in my controller before I call my `update_divs.js.erb`?

If I'm off-base on how this should be done, please teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly,you need after_action methods to use.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action

UPD

```
BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :some_action_name, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def some_action_name
  end
end

HomeController < BaseController
  def show
  end
end
```

In this case BaseController is inherited by ApplicationController, we placed some_action_name method to BaseController and inherited HomeController from BaseController. We defined that some_action_name must ne executed before actions show, edit, update, destroy. It means that now some_action_name will be executed before these methods of HomeController too.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this is the best action to take. I would put my method in the application controller so I can use on both my home controller and x controller?

Comment: Yes, you can place it either in application controller(if you have only 2 controllers), or you can create parent controller for your both controllers (if you have other controllers that musn't inherit this before_action)

Comment: Interesting...which would be best? By parent controller, do you mean super controller? Can you give an example in your answer of how to apply inheritance?